# Is language L context-free?

Tags: computer-science

Is following language context-free?
Alphabet: {a,b,c,d}
L = {w | w is not in {aabbc,abc,add}}

I think it is:

{aabbc},{abc},{add} are all regular.

Because of closure properties(Union)  R = {w | w is in {aabbc,abc,add}} is also regular.
Because of closure of complement (L is complement of R) L is also regular.

So L is regular, and since all regular languages are context-free : L is context-free.

Comment: You're right. In fact, any language which is finite or cofinite (a finite number of words is not in it) is regular, and so context-free.

Comment: @Yuval, do make that a proper answer, so that this does not end up being periodically revived by the annoying *Community* user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. In fact, every finite language is regular, and so is it's complement. They're context-free a fortiori.